# Auto Format Date with Numbers and Slashes only

Tags: jquery, regex, date, formatting, numbers

I am trying to auto format a date where it displays as `"MM/DD/YYYY"` but only allows numbers and the forward slashes.

Here is what I have so far, and it does everything I want except restrict to numbers and slashes only:

```
$('#date').keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    $date = $(this);

    if (key !== 8) {
        if ($date.val().length === 0) {
            $date.val($date.val() + '');
        }
        if ($date.val().length === 2) {
            $date.val($date.val() + '/');
        }
        if ($date.val().length === 5) {
            $date.val($date.val() + '/');
        }
    }
});
```

I do NOT want to add any plugins or masks, I am just looking for the code to do what I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking up the [ascii code](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/slash-forward-slash-fraction-bar-division-ascii-code-47.html) for a forward slash is `47`.
The solution below allows only numeric characters.

```
$('#date').on('keypress', function (ev) {
    var key = ev.keyCode || ev.which;

    // this prevents other characters but numeric
    if (key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

So change the 48 to 47 and it allows forward slashes too.

Note the use of the `keypress` event, so you can capture the event for characters (letters, numbers, ...) before you allow value input of any other key. Like you can type by holding the ALT+numeric value.

That's why you'll be fine by capturing `ev.keyCode || ev.which` and don't allow the event to fire in a certain range `key > 31 && (key < 47 || key > 57)`

**ADDITIONALLY**

The next thing to do ofcourse is validating the input value as a date.
Something like:

```
var date = $('#date').val().split('/'),
    day = parseInt(date[0], 10),
    month = parseInt(date[1], 10),
    year = parseInt(date[2], 10),
    invalidDay = day < 1 || day > 31,
    invalidMonth = month < 1 || month > 12,
    invalidYear = year < 1900 || year > 2016; // depends on the reason for the datepicker

if (invalidDay || invalidMonth || invalidYear){
    event.preventDefault();
    // OR AUTO CORRECT
} else {
    // AUTO FORMAT!!?!#@$%£
    // do whatever you want with the values in date[] for your idea to make it work
    // example: auto pad numbers below 10 with a 0
    if (date[0].length < 2) {
        date[0] = '0' + date[0];
    }

    if (date[1].length < 2) {
        date[1] = '0' + date[1];
    }

    $('#date').val(date.join('/'));
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for the response.  How would I implement that to where it would AUTO FORMAT with the forward slash?

Comment: For my answer this is partly done in `Here is what I have so far, and it does everything I want except restrict to numbers and slashes only`. Perhaps you didn't think this through ... ?

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope you'll notice the small dose of sarcasm and realize why libraries can be helpfull. You'll have to come up with more information or a working jsfiddle in order to help you more specifically.